# How do I search an entire model based on the value returned by a virtual attribute on that model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model `Property`, and I have a virtual attribute that is defined like this:

```
  def uid_type
    if mls? && mls.to_i != 0
      "MLS"
    elsif property_identifier? && property_identifier.to_i != 0
      "PID"
    else
      "ID"
    end
  end
```

Such that if I have a property `p`, when I query that virtual attribute, this is what I see:

```
> p.uid_type
 => "MLS"
```

Basically, what I want to do is create a scope on my model to return all properties that have `uid_type == 'MLS'`.

How do I do that?

**Edit 1**

If I try this:

```
Property.where('properties.uid_type == "MLS"').count
   (4.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties" WHERE (properties.uid_type == "MLS")
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column properties.uid_type does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties"  WHERE (properties.uid_typ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write your own scope, ActiveRecord doesn't help much with custom methods.

```
scope :with_mls_uid_type, -> { where.not(mls: [nil, '']) }
```

Which will translate to:

```
SELECT "properties".* 
FROM "properties" 
WHERE ("properties"."mls" IS NOT NULL) 
AND ("properties"."mls" != '')
```

If your tag is correct and you're still on Rails 3.2 then you won't have `.not` and you will have to do:

```
where("mls IS NOT NULL AND mls != ''")
```

Comment: I was just about to ask about Rails 3.2 and the `not`. So I tried your example, and I am getting the following error: `> Property.where("mls IS NOT NULL AND mls !=0").count
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties" WHERE (mls IS NOT NULL AND mls !=0)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <> integer                                                            
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Btw. are you sure you know how `mls.to_i != 0` works if `mls` is a string? `"5foo".to_i == 5`, but `"foo".to_i == 0`. It's important for the scope as it's not as simple to write in PostgreSQL and might not be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I am honestly not sure. This is a legacy codebase I am taking over, so I am just now digging through everything. But I will look into that and do proper error handling as needed. Thanks for the answer and the feedback!